Выполнить 3 команды bash одной строкой
В теории
exec('ffmpeg ... && ffmpeg ... && ffmpeg ...')

Должно сработать, но нет возможности проверить. Так как результат выполнения приложений первых 2 команд необходимо записать в переменную. И значения 2 переменных вставить в выполнение третьей команды...
Вопрос в том, как одной строкой из php поочередно запустить выполнение 3 задач.
Результат первых двух команд записать в переменную и при запуске третей команды, вставить результаты 2 предыдущих...
Возможно такое, как?
Пытаюсь выполнить команду в команде, не выходит.
ffmpeg -i /video.mp4 -c:v libwebp -lavfi 'fps=1/30,$(echo ffmpeg -i /video.mp4 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  \$NF }' | tail -1),split=2,scale=-1:594' -vsync vfr -start_number 0 /img%d.webp

Ругается на синтаксис

если что то подобное https://gist.github.com/des1roer/efa759d963a0e69e8a5ec782b754bd86

Второй вариант
echo "ffmpeg -i /video.mp4 -c:v libwebp -lavfi 'fps=1/30," >> 1.sh && fmpeg -i ./video.mp4 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1 >> 1.sh && echo ",split=2,scale=-1:594' -vsync vfr -start_number 0 /img%d.webp" >> 1.sh && tr --delete '\n' < 1.sh > 2.sh && rm 1.sh && chmod +x 2.sh && sleep 1 && ./2.sh && rm ./2.sh


Самое простое - написать небольшой shell-скрипт (если у Вас Unix), либо ps -скрипт (если у Вас ОС Windows)
Приведу пример для Unix.
Создадим для примера три скрипта, первый выводит "1", второй "2", третий выводит два передаваемых на вход параметра.
//script1.php
echo "1";

//script2.php
echo "2";

//script3.php
echo $argv[1].";".$argv[2];

Пишем shell-скрипт
#run.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
#в переменную var1 запоминаем результат работы первого скрипта
var1=`php -q script1.php`
#в переменную var2 запоминаем результат работы второго скрипта
var2=`php -q script2.php`
#результат их работы передаем на вход третьему скрипту
php -q script3.php $var1 $var2

Соответственно, все что Вам нужно будет вызывать этот shell-скрипт внутри php-скрипта
exec("run.sh");


Было бы здорово, если в php запустить поочередно 3 команды. Еще бы было бы круче когда не в переменную результат выполнения запоминаем. А сразу ffmpeg команду разместить в другой ffmpeg команде. Тут пробывал, пытался. Вся соль в том, что не удается либо как то криво работает когда необходимо из под php запустить приложение в фоне. Вот если бы команда в команде, то тут трудностей точно не было бы.

У меня получается, необходимо из под php запустить скрипт в фоне и каждую команду в скрипте также запустить в фоне. Иначе якс запрос зависает и не возвращает ответа, либо возвращает 200 код без ответа. Так или иначе, даже в скрипте необходимо каждую команду запустить поочередно в фоне. Пока не пробовал, очень хочется попытаться команду в команде, понять возможно ли такое...

Пока работает как часы, если одно приложение в фоне запустить из php. А вот с тремя, получить результат первой и поставить во вторую, не выходит...

Добавил пример, как я пытаюсь разместить команду в команде. Не знаю, как верно скобки прописывать в данном случаи...
